# Error-reporting framework for .net

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, error-reporting, bug-tracking

is there an error-reporting-framework you would suggest for use in .net. I need possibilities like e-mail-reporting with fileappending to e-mail. The user should have the possibility to add information to the report and also should have the possibility to remove report-files, i.e. if they contains privacy-critical data. There also should be a possibility of taking an automated screenshot.
The needed framework should also include error-reporting guis. It should give me the possibility to create own guis for error-reporting.

I already use **log4net**, but there it isn't possible, as far as i know, to show a gui for error-reporting to the user.

Would be nice if there are any advices,

Greetings, Martin

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224/good-crash-reporting-library-in-c

Comment: Visual Studio Application Insights is what you need! https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)? It does all the error handling elements you are talking of. You might look at [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for the bug-tacking bits you want.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 4):

I am familiar with the "Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging Block" and "Log4Net" and both of these fit into your requirements (having multiple log listeners)
Here is a page that compares these two: http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2005/02/18/376191.aspx

Comment: I use log4net already, but has log4net the possibility to create a crash-report window? It isn't possible to generate automated mail with logfiles because of privacy-reasons. The user must have the possibility to decide if he reports a crash.

Answer (score 4):

Roll your own exception handler. Use below code in your program.cs class. It will automatically Send mail when exception occurs.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading; 

namespace ExceptionHandlerTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.ThreadException +=
                new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

            // Your designer generated commands.
        }

        static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e) 
        {

            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("your Gmail address", "Your name");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("email address where you want to receive reports", "Your name");
            const string fromPassword = "your password";
            const string subject = "exception report";
            Exception exception = e.Exception;
            string body = exception.Message + "\n" + exception.Data + "\n" + exception.StackTrace + "\n" + exception.Source;

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                //You can also use SendAsync method instead of Send so your application begin invoking instead of waiting for send mail to complete. SendAsync(MailMessage, Object) :- Sends the specified e-mail message to an SMTP server for delivery. This method does not block the calling thread and allows the caller to pass an object to the method that is invoked when the operation completes. 
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so good, thank you! I wish i could accept your answer as correct. I used this in my project and works perfectly. I've found out if you catch the exception then it doesnt call the mail report. But i've made a class from it and i call it in "try, catch", so the user still gets an error report visualy.

Comment: I love the simplicity but I don't like hard coded passwords in programs, open to abuse, should be a way to wrap it up so it can't be easily viewed from the MSIL assembly.

Comment: @rolls I created library out of this code that doesn't require email for SMTP now. It uses Drdump service to collect crashes. You can find it at https://crashreporterdotnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

Check out the logging framework made by [The Object Guy](http://www.theobjectguy.com/dotnetlog/)

Answer (score 3):

Red Gate has a product called [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/smartassembly/index.htm) that does error reporting. I haven't used it myself, but the company has a good reputation.

Comment: Beware that you can not use it in visual studio online build pipeline because it requires installation with license key. If you can - message the solution to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx),  you have a logging and an exception handling application log fully configurable and extensible.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Microsoft WER](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/maintain/StartWER.mspx), however you need to register at Winqual and your company needs to have a VeriSign ID. Too much a hassle for many people.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Enterprise Library](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib), latest version [4.1-October 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1643758B-2986-47F7-B529-3E41584B6CE5&displaylang=en) is widely used for Exception handling and logging among other things. There's also a nice GUI builder that will modify your app.config or web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). I'm not sure about emailing, though. However, it is extensible. Plus you can get the source code!